# How to download embedded mongo db version 4.0+ for windows..?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

Using url **https://downloads.mongodb.org/win32** can able to download only 3.5.5 version and not able to download 4+ versions.

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/community

Comment: I have explored the site, there is no option to download embedded mongo @TusharGupta-curioustushar